# Null pointer exception with java program handling image files

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

So I have a program that is supposed to display a card image file. (It is for another program that does a War card game.)

However, when I run it, I receive this error:

```
Error opening file.
The first node is: Node [suit=3, card =2, next=null]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Card.getImage(Card.java:118)
    at Card.main(Card.java:187)
```

What am I doing wrong?  I have a partner with exact same code, yet his works fine.  We are both coding in Eclipse.

My code:

```
public class Card {

    //// card definitions ////
    public static final int DUMMY = 9999999;    // a constant indicating a dummy node
    public static final int CLUB = 0;       // clubs
    public static final int SPADE = 1;      // spades
    public static final int HEART = 2;      // hearts
    public static final int DIAMOND = 3;    // diamonds
    public static final String IMAGEFILENAME = "classic-playing-cards.png"; // image file
    public static final int CARDWIDTH = 73; // card width
    public static final int CARDHEIGHT = 98;    // card height

    //// class member ////
    private static BufferedImage img = null;

    //// data members ////
    private int suit;           // the suit  
    private int value;          // the card value, 0=ace, 1=deuce, 2=3 ... 10=9, Jack=10, Queen=11, King=12
    private JLabel image;       // the card image file
    private Card next;          // a link to the next node

    //// Constructors ////
    public Card() {
        // initialize to be a dummy node by default
        suit = DUMMY;
        value = DUMMY;
        image = null;
        next = null;

        // check to see if the buffered image is loaded
        if (img == null) {
            // not yet loaded, so load it now!
            loadBufferedImage();
        }
    }


   public String getSuitName() {
      if (suit == CLUB) 
         return "Club";
      else
      if(suit == SPADE)
         return "Spade";
      else
      if(suit == HEART)
         return "Heart";
      else
      if(suit == DIAMOND)
         return "Diamond";
      else
         return "Invalid suit number.";
      }


    //// Set up the buffered image
    public void loadBufferedImage() {
        try {
            // get the path to the image file name
            java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(IMAGEFILENAME);
            if (imgURL != null) {
                // read the image file, using the path
                img = ImageIO.read(new File(imgURL.getFile()));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Couldn't find file: " + IMAGEFILENAME);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error opening file.");
            image = new JLabel("Error");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the suit
     */
    public int getSuit() {//suit getter
        return suit;
    }

    /**
     * @return the card
     */
    public int getCard() {//card getter
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * @return the card's image
     */
    public JLabel getImage() {
        // as long as it's not a dummy card
        if (value != DUMMY && suit != DUMMY) {
            // create a JLabel for display, for just the card that we want
            image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img.getSubimage(CARDWIDTH*value,CARDHEIGHT*suit,CARDWIDTH,CARDHEIGHT)));
        } else {
            // oops, error!  just display the text "DUMMY"
            image = new JLabel("DUMMY");
        }
        return image;
    }

    /**
     * @return the next
     */
    public Card getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    /**
     * @param suit the suit to set
     */
    public void setSuit(int suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    /**
     * @param card the card to set
     */
    public void setCard(int card) {
        this.value = card;
    }

    /**
     * @param next the next to set
     */
    public void setNext(Card next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    //// deepCopy ////
    /* create a duplicate copy of this node */
    public Card deepCopy() {
        Card copy = new Card();  // the duplicate node

        // fill contents
        copy.setSuit(suit);  // duplicate the data
        copy.setCard(value);
        // do not need to set the image, since we recalculate it each time
        copy.setNext(null);  // set next to be a null pointer, this node is not in a list

        // return the copy
        return copy;
    }

    //// Auto generate toString() using Eclipse ////
    public String toString() {
        return "Node [suit=" + suit + ", card =" + value + ", next=" + next + "]";
    }

    //// main() for testing ////
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create a card:  the 3 of diamonds
        // REMEMBER:  the card # is off-by-one from the face value
        Card firstnode = new Card();
        firstnode.setSuit(Card.DIAMOND);
        firstnode.setCard(2);
        System.out.println("The first node is: " + firstnode);

        // this is a super-basic JFrame, used only for really basic testing
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Card");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(firstnode.getImage(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);     
    }
}
```

Comment: what line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the line indicated, and see who's causing the exception.

Comment: The line that is throwing the exception is 118:
      image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img.getSubimage(CARDWIDTH*value,CARDHEIGHT*suit,CARDWIDTH,CARDHEIGHT)));

and 187:   frame.getContentPane().add(firstnode.getImage(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

Comment: According to your code; you're missing the 3 of Diamonds. Where do you set IMAGEFILENAME?

Comment: Right below the class declaration. The file that is being used is a locally saved file.

     public static final String IMAGEFILENAME = "classic-playing-cards.png";

Comment: My best guess is that `img` is still `null` when you execute `image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img.getSubimage(CARDWIDTH*value,CARDHEIGHT*suit,CARDWIDTH,CARDHEIGHT)));`. You may want to put `if` there and check for `null`. If it's indeed null print an error message, otherwise perform the assignment. It's just a temporary **debugging** solution.

Comment: Where is `classic-playing-cards.png` file located?

Comment: debug and see what's null.  Then debug and see why that is not getting set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that I can't tell why the result is different.

There's exception in loadBufferedImage method during the ImageIO.read() call which throws NullPointerException at img.getSubimage();.

A possible fix is to use getResourceAsStream in loadBufferedImage():

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(IMAGEFILENAME);
img = ImageIO.read(in);
in.close();
```

Please see if this works for you.